# How to handle a highly right skewed dataset without 'hurting' it too much?

Tags: r, regression, skewness, logarithm

I have a freemium mobile app usage dataset. I want to perform a regression with the average spending per month (continuous) as a dependent, and if they came via referral program (binary) as the independent variable.

However, the average spendings per month are highly right skewed (lots of 'minnows', only a few 'whales'). I've read about methods like winsorizing or log-transformation - however, also about the critics. As it is the nature of the freemium business, I don't want to winsorize or trim too much.

Is there anything I can do with a non-naturally distributed and heteroscedastic dataset? Any experiences?

Comment: If you only have one binary x variable, then you can just compute aggregate statistics per group - mean , median, quantiles, ... - whatever your business decision/ analysis requires. Also look into customer lifetime value (clv) modeling.  I guess you have lots of y=0 too.  Ultimately, What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg there is the caveat that standard significance tests might not work with the skewed data. That said, I think you're correct that displaying the detailed information needed to make the business decision is key. With this type of data, bootstrapping would probably be more reliable than standard tests to get error estimates.

Comment: For such data a semiparametric model often works well, e.g., the Cox proportional hazards model or the proportional odds model.  More [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).